# Change Jupyter QtConsole settings

Tags: python, jupyter

It is possible to make persistent changes to settings for default settings on Windows 7?
I would like to change font-size and shell size.

Comment: Yes, there are config files: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#configuration

Comment: Thanks. I managed to change font size and family which resulted in a slightly larger window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036520/setting-default-configuration-for-jupyter-qtconsole

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QtConsole has configurable via the ConsoleWidget. Start with:

```
> ipython qtconsole --ConsoleWidget.font_size=11
```

Comment: But these are not persistent changes, unlike the answer of [Josh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18904744/2521769)

Answer (score 29):

Instructions on configuring the ipython command line application are [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/ipython.html) on IPython's web site.  Step-by-step instructions for configuring the font size in particular:

First, create the IPython profile.  Simply running IPython or IPython's QtConsole should do this for you, but if you have to do it by hand, run

```
ipython profile create
```

Second, create an IPython config file:

- Windows - `%USERPROFILE%\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_config.py`
- Linux or OS X - `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

Sample IPython contents:

```
c = get_config()

c.IPythonWidget.font_size = 11
c.IPythonWidget.font_family = 'Consolas'
```

There's a more detailed sample config file at [ipython.org](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/index.html).

Comment: That last link is now broken, I think http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/index.html is the updated equivalent.

Comment: @schodge - Updated.  Thanks!  (In the future, feel free to propose an edit yourself, instead of just adding a comment.)

Comment: @JoshKelley `ipython profile create` shows syntax error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Works for me, so I don't know what's wrong. If you're still having problems, a separate question, with more detail, would be easier than discussing via comments.

Comment: schodge's updated link works.

Also, for the intro guide: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/intro.html

Comment: If you want to change the size of initial window, use `c.IPythonWidget.height = 36`, `c.IPythonWidget.width = 96` (value refers to the number of rows or columns).

Comment: Your post describes how to configure IPython. The OP wants to know how to configure the jupyter qtconsole.  When I make changes to my ipython_config.py file, they are not recognized by the console opened with `%qtconsole` in jupyter. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With the most recent versions of IPython/Jupyter:

1. The relevant config file is now `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`

   At the top of the file we do `c = get_config()`
2. The relevant command for font size is `c.ConsoleWidget.font_size = 12`
3. (See: [a reference for the other configurable options](https://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/config_options.html).)
4. Another setting is `c.JupyterWidget.syntax_style = "trac"` (for example), which is a colour-scheme setting. [List of schemes](https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/3hfflo/jupyter_qtconsole_colors/). It is possible to create a custom scheme: the easiest way seems to be to put a `your_name_here.py` into the `$PYTHON/Lib/site-packages/pygments/styles` directory, of a similar format to the other files there. (Configuring things this way sounds a bit fragile, but the other [suggested way, of registering the custom scheme](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/#creating-own-styles), seems similarly fragile.) More styles may be specified using CSS. In the config file as above:

   ```
   c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet = '/path/to/your_name_here.css'
   ```

   An example "LightBG" stylesheet is given [here](https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). (There are only a few CSS classes. Some of the default highlighting still stays as default, with no way to change them using either the CSS or the Pygments style file. For example, the highlighting of a `SyntaxError` message stays at the default. This might have been fixed in the most recent version — see the [discussion here](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/49).)

---

Here's a bonus. A shortcut for changing IPython qtconsole settings using one function call.

Put the following code into a file named `IPYTHON_PROFILE_DIR/startup/startup.ipy`. (For some reason this is still under `~/.ipython`, not `~/.jupyter`.) It can be named something other than "`startup.ipy`", but the extension must be `.ipy`, not `.py`.

```
def edit_config():
    profile_path = !ipython locate profile
    !{'gvim "%s/ipython_config.py"' % profile_path[0]}
```

(Replace "`gvim`" with your preferred editor.)

Now, whenever you need to tweak your Jupyter Qtconsole configuration, you'll be able to bring it up using:

```
In [1]: edit_config()
```

Comment: The actual line I use is: `!{'gvim -p "{0}/ipython_config.py" "{0}/../../.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py" '.format(profile_path[0])}` This is to open both config files in tabs.

Comment: When launching "qtconsole" with the the most recent version of Anaconda Navigator, the `c = get_config()` seems to "hang" launching of the console.  Removing that and just using the variable `c` as above works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the config files? http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.config.loader.html#IPython.config.loader.Config

Answer (score 1):

Step by step, one would do like this:

In bash under Windows 7 ([MingW](http://www.mingw.org/)), I would get help straight from IPython with

```
/c/Python27/Scripts/IPython.exe qtconsole --help-all | grep font2.
```

Then you just have to edit ipython_config.py (which is located in your .ipython home directory. In Windows 7: **/c/Users/< your_user >/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py**

```
c.IPythonWidget.font_size = 11
c.IPythonWidget.font_family = 'Calibri'
```

For the window size, look at this [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3152). You may need to install a recent version.

Answer (score 1):

you can right click on the ipython windows and select "Default". you can set your default configuration from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Works for linux:**

Use https://bitbucket.org/joon/color-schemes-for-ipython-qt-console

```
pip install jupyter_qtconsole_colorschemes
```

In `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`,
you can further configure other settings mentioned here(https://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/config_options.html):

Example:

```
color_theme = 'monokai'  # specify color theme

import pkg_resources
c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
    "jupyter_qtconsole_colorschemes", "{}.css".format(color_theme))

c.JupyterWidget.syntax_style = color_theme
c.ConsoleWidget.font_size=15
```

Comment: For me, setting `c.JupyterWidget.syntax_style` alone worked. But when also setting `c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet`, it did not work.