# Changing the configuration file of IPython QtConsole has no effect

Tags: python, ipython

On my Windows 7 system, making changes to the IPython configuration file for the Qt console doesn't seem to have any effect. I just use (and changed) the default profile (not explicitly stated in the commandline, but tried and no effect either). The configuration file seems to be present in the proper location:

`C:\Users\<user name>\.ipython\profile_default\ipython_qtconsole_config.py`

So what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906938/change-ipython-qtconsole-settings) post did not work out for me.

I use IPython 0.13.1 on Python 3.2.3. For Qt bindings, I use PySide 1.1.2.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the Profile dir is correct with `ipython profile locate` ? And Try to start with the `--debug` flag to have more info maybe...

Comment: When I do `ipython3 profile list` then it returns that there is a `default` profile in `C:\Users\<user name>\.ipython`.
The --debug option tells me:
`C:\Python32\Scripts>ipython3 qtconsole --pylab=inline --profile==default --debug 
[IPythonQtConsoleApp] Config changed:
[IPythonQtConsoleApp] {'Application': {'log_level': 10}, 'BaseIPythonApplication': {'profile': '=default'}, 'IPKernelApp': {'pylab': 'inline'}}
[IPythonQtConsoleApp] Profile '=default' not found.
[IPythonQtConsoleApp] Exiting application: ipython-qtconsole`

Comment: Sorry, there was I typo in above comment and therefore the part about the --debug option should be ignored.
Your advise to enable the --debug option was helpful, thanks. An exception was raised while loading the config file and I found the problem: an almost invisible space was in front of the enabled code lines in the config file :(