# Failed to change font size in ipython qtconsole

Tags: ipython

I tried to change the `ipython qtconsole` font size with reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904744/2185472) in stackoverflow; however, the font size refused to change no matter how I change the `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`.

```
➜  ~  ipython profile locate
/home/nick/.ipython/profile_default

➜  ~  head .ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py 
# Configuration file for ipython.
c = get_config()    
c.IPythonWidget.font_size = 16
c.IPythonWidget.font_family = 'Source Code Pro'

➜  ~  uname -a
Linux nick-thinkpad 4.2.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 08:13:28 CET 2015 x86
_64 GNU/Linux                                                                  

➜  ~  ipython --version
4.0.0
```

To my suprise, `ipython qtconsole --ConsoleWidget.font_size=16` works. What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From version 4.0 on `ipython qtconsole` is deprecated (because of the [big split](http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/04/15/the-big-split/)). Instead, use `jupyter qtconsole`. You can set the fontsize by adding `c.ConsoleWidget.font_size = 12` to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` (this also sets the font size for `ipython qtconsole`).
Be aware of a [bug in jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/pull/52) that does not allow you to automatically create a default config file. For now, you just have to create that file manually.

Comment: Thank you for the `ipython -> jupyter` information, and the solution for this dilemma.