# How to render large parenthesis correctly in sympy?

Tags: python, latex, sympy, pprint

I am trying to render simple algebraic expressions in either qtconsole or a terminal using `pprint`, but the results are almost misleading. Here's a minimal example

```
from sympy import pprint, simplify, init_printing
from sympy.abc import a, b

init_printing()
c = a - b**2
pprint(simplify(c**2))
print(simplify(c**2))
```

I tried this code in both `jupyer qtconsole` and in rxvt-unicode terminal and both don't display multiple level parenthsis correctly. On the terminal I get rectangular symbols where the brackets should be. qtconsole is even worse as it doesn't show parenthsis.

[image]

This is extremely confusing when the expressions get more complicated. Please let me know if I am missing something or if sympy can be configured to display that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pprint` uses Unicode characters to print parentheses by default, like

```
        2
⎛     2⎞ 
⎝a - b ⎠
```

It seems your qtconsole isn't rendering them, which probably means the font you are using doesn't support them.

My recommendations:

- Install DejaVu Sans Mono and set your qtconsole font to that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18904744/161801). DejaVu Sans Mono is the best font for the Unicode characters used by SymPy, in my experience.
- Install LaTeX on your computer. If you run `init_printing` in the qtconsole SymPy detects that LaTeX is installed, it will render math using it (`pprint` will still render text).

If neither of the above is an option for you the workaround is to use `pprint(expr, use_unicode=False)`, which will print the expression using only ASCII characters. It won't look as nice, but it should render correctly in any monospace font.

Comment: Another option is to use the notebook instead of the qtconsole, which will render math using MathJax (and doesn't require installing LaTeX).

Comment: DejaVu fonts solved it for qt console so I am assuming my font in the teminal can be fixed in the same way.I like the notebook suggestion - it actually fits my intended purpose best, but it seems to mess up the parenthesis too, despite mathjax available!