# Setting default configuration for Jupyter QtConsole

Tags: python, jupyter, qtconsole

I have Jupyter QtConsole installed in Ubuntu 16.04. How can I set default configuration like font family, size and initial imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs on configuration options for jupyter](https://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/config_options.html) will be very helpful here.

In short, open `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` in your favorite text editor and find your options of interest.

- Font family : `c.ConsoleWidget.font_family`
- Font size : `c.ConsoleWidget.font_size`

Startup scripts and initial imports will be a little more complicated since those are properties of the ipython kernel, which will need to be set in your ipython config.  In `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py`,

- Initial imports : `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['import numpy as np','import pandas as pd']`

Comment: In ~/.jupyter there no file named 'jupyter_qtconsole_config.py'. I also presume 'c' (as in c.ConsoleWidget.font_family' is a class. How do I get c?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, just run `touch ~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`.  "c" and other config classes will be loaded as globals when you first start up qtconsole, so you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: To generate default configuration, you can also run  `jupyter qtconsole --generate-config` in terminal. `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`will be generated with a lot default settings.

Comment: @Richard - The comment is much worth posting as an answer.