# Jupyter QtConsole: select one of the built in CSSs as the default via configuration

Tags: css, jupyter-console

I am using Jupyter in Windows.
I mean to change coloring of the QT console.

**How can I select one of the built in CSSs as the default, via configuration file?**

I mean to avoid passing it as an argument as in `jupyter qtconsole --style monokai`.
I would rather use a configuration file, e.g. file1 = `%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter\jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`
What I ultimately want to do is write `monokai` in some configuration file, and have the QTconsole load the built-in `monokai`.

What I tried so far:

1. As a test, execute
   `jupyter qtconsole --style monokai`.
   It actually brought monokai (white fgr on dark gray bgr). Moreover, it combined well with my selected `c.ConsoleWidget.font_size = 12` in file1.
2. Then, trying to use my own css.
   I copied a `monokai.css` file in `C:\Users\user1` (I have quite a few in my system, but I guess any one should work for the most basic stuff).
   In file1 I included one of the lines

   ```
   c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet = u'C:/Users/user1/monokai.css'
   c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet = 'C:/Users/user1/monokai.css'
   c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.stylesheet = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\monokai.css'
   ```

   None worked.

If I made this work, I would still have to find how to replace the specification of a file as a location by a simple CSS name among the built-in.

PS: I know I could also set a Windows shortcut that launches `jupyter qtconsole --style monokai`.
I also mean to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, but I am not certain it is the only one, or if it is the most portable across systems.
Note: there might be some issues, yet to be solved, in the way this configuration works, see https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/334

Use

```
c.JupyterWidget.syntax_style = 'monokai'
```

in file `%USERPROFILE%\.jupyter\jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`
or `~\.jupyter\jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37850255/2707864).